# Web Scraping BoardGameGeek with RVest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm pretty much brand new to web scraping with rvest.. and really new to most everything except Qlik coding.

I am attempting to scrape data found at board game geek, see the below link.  Using inspect, it certainly seems possible, but yet rvest is not finding the tags.  I first thought I had to go through the whole javascript process using V8 (javascript is called at the top of the html), but when I just use html_text on the whole document, all the information I need is in there.

***UPDATE: It appears to be in JSON.  I used a combination of notepad++ and web tool to clean it and load into R.  Any recommendations on tutorials/demos for how to do this systematically?  I have all the links I need to loop through, but not sure how to go from the html_text output to a clean JSON input via code. ***

I provided examples below, but I need to scrape the majority of the data elements available, so not looking for code to copy and paste but rather the best method to pursue.  See below.

Link: https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/63888/innovation

HTML Example I am trying to pull from.  Span returns nothing with html_nodes so I couldn't even start there.

```
<span ng-if="min > 0" class="ng-binding ng-scope">45</span>
```

OR

```
<a title="Civilization" ng-href="/boardgamecategory/1015/civilization" class="ng-binding" href="/boardgamecategory/1015/civilization">Civilization</a>
```

Javscript sections at top of page like this: about 8 of them:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cf.geekdo-static.com/static/geekcollection_master2_5e84926ab7e90.js"></script>
```

When I just use html_text on the whole object I can find see all the elements I am looking for e.g.:

```
\"minplaytime\":\"30\" OR {\"name\":\"Deck, Bag, and Pool Building\"
```

I'm assuming this is JSON?  Is there a way to parse the html_text output, or another method?  Is it easier just to rush the javascript at the top of the page using V8?  Is there an easy guide for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you aware, that BGG has an API? Documentation can be found here: [URL](https://boardgamegeek.com/wiki/page/BGG_XML_API2)

The code will be provided as XML file. So for your example you can get the ID of your game - your example is 63888 (its in the URL). So the xml file can be found at: https://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi2/thing?id=63888

You can read the info with this code:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

game_data <- read_xml("https://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi2/thing?id=63888")
game_data %>% 
  html_nodes("name[type=primary]") %>% 
  html_attr("value") %>% 
  as.character()
#> [1] "Innovation"
```

By inspecting the xml file you can choose what node you want to export.

<sup>Created on 2020-04-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank You!  I connected to it and am running a loop that is timed for every 5 seconds and takes 8 days if everything goes perfect.  But it seems to be working good.   I am going to post a follow up question about how to transform my data in a quicker fashion.  Essentially I pulled everything into a table of "gameID","Field","Value".  So if it has multiple of a field, such as publisher, it will have one row per unique value.  I want to then rotate this out to get a concatenated list as one field and the count as another.  I can do this for one, but not sure if there's a systematic way.